# Should the tag [re-zero] be given a synonym [rezero]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I often do searches by tag name, manually surrounding the search term by square brackets.  A search for **[re:zero]** finds no hits, though.  In fact, the colon is auto-removed and the search is actually made for **[rezero]**.  So that is actually what got no hits. Similarly, a search for **rezero** (no brackets and no inner punctuation) finds no hits, and it probably never will unless someone types it as part of their question or answer.

Note that if you search without the brackets, then **re:zero** does find appropriate questions. This is quite fortunate, because that is the actual English name of the series, with the colon.  The results of that search showed me that the tag name is **[re-zero]**, with a dash instead of a colon.

I suggest that the tag **[rezero]** be created as a synonym for **[re-zero]**.  While it won't solve all search problems concerning the series, it would help some.

Comment: FWIW, the tag-searcher (at http://anime.stackexchange.com/tags) is smarter, and will find the tag whether you type in "rezero", "re-zero", or "re:zero".

Comment: @senshin Yes, searches for tags is very smart.  It can even find tags when you only used a middle or last word!  What I mean though is use of the normal search at the top of SE's title bar.  Searching for **naruto** will find all posts that use the name, even ones just casually referencing it.  Searching for **[naruto]** will find only the questions to be specifically tagged as being about the series.  Same with **[cowboy-bebop]** (I know to replace spaces with dashes.)

Comment: Unfortunately, SE’s search engine is not as intelligent as the tagging system.

Comment: @Jan I'm not complaining at all.  SE has fantastic features, such as the live preview as you write a question or answer.  I'm sure they're constantly improving.  Until everything is "perfect", the synonym system helps to fill in a gap.  That is why I ask for one here.

Comment: @RichF Oh yes, I fully agree with you. A lot works great on SE and especially the fact that the search actually *respects quotes and asterisks* is worth ten upvotes by itself. However, there are still shortcomings, which I intended to address in my comment just in a matter-of-fact way =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't like the idea of having a proliferation of these not-really-synonyms, but [that horse bolted a long time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259377/). No point in being a synonym purist on this site, I guess.

[rezero] and some other things [are now synonyms](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/re-zero/synonyms) of [re-zero].

Comment: Thank you.  This site already uses some advanced technology, so it won't surprise me when the *Search* starts to automatically recognize misspellings and alternative spellings.  That should reduce the manual synonym chasing a lot.

Comment: Was the synonym [rezero] removed at some point, do you know? I don't see it listed as a synonym now.